# phpbb3 like and unlike issue

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

Hi I am facing an issue the reputation system works perfectly fine when i use prosilver theme. but i am not getting the like and and unlike images in prosilver_se.i understood where is the problem but could not resolve it. there is a page viewtopic_body.html where i am calling the like and unlike feature

```
<!-- IF S_REPUTATION and S_FORUM_REPUTATION -->
                <ul class="post-reputation<!-- IF postrow.RS_POST_CLASS --> {postrow.RS_POST_CLASS}<!-- ENDIF -->">
                    <li class="rate-good-icon"><!-- IF postrow.S_GIVE_REPUTATION --><a href="#" onclick="jRS.positive('{postrow.POST_ID}', event, this); return false;" <!-- IF postrow.RS_GIVEN_POINT gt 0 -->class="{postrow.RS_POST_CLASS}" title="{L_RS_YOU_RATED} {postrow.RS_GIVEN_POINT}"<!-- ELSE --> title="{L_RS_RATE_POST}"<!-- ENDIF -->><span>{L_RS_ADD_POINTS}</span></a><!-- ENDIF --></li>
                    <li class="reputation {postrow.RS_BOX_COLOR}"><div title="{L_RS_POST_REPUTATION}"><!-- IF postrow.S_VIEW_REPUTATION --><a href="#" onclick="jRS.postdetails('{postrow.POST_ID}'); return false;"><!-- ENDIF -->{postrow.POST_REPUTATION}<!-- IF postrow.S_VIEW_REPUTATION --></a><!-- ENDIF --></div></li>
                    <!-- IF postrow.S_GIVE_REPUTATION && postrow.S_GIVE_NEGATIVE--><li class="rate-bad-icon"><a href="#" onclick="jRS.negative('{postrow.POST_ID}', event, this); return false;" <!-- IF postrow.RS_GIVEN_POINT lt 0 --> class="{postrow.RS_POST_CLASS}" title="{L_RS_YOU_RATED} {postrow.RS_GIVEN_POINT}"<!-- ELSE --> title="{L_RS_RATE_POST}"<!-- ENDIF --> onclick="return false;"><span>{L_RS_SUBTRACT_POINTS}</span></a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                </ul>
                <br />
            <!-- ENDIF -->
```

it is showing `{ RS_ADD_POINTS } { RS_SUBTRACT_POINTS }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be due to style issue. phpbb is saving the style & themes in database also. Check out the table `phpbb_styles_theme`. there is a column `theme_data`. check out the styles mentioned here. check & compare `prosilver` & `prosilver_se` css files. better replace all of them with _se.